# LinkedIn native sharing iOS issue

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, sharing

Our team develops an app which has a possibility to share posts via iOS native sharing. And we have some questions regarding LinkedIn app:

1. We can't share images via LinkedIn iOS app. The image is present on the preview, but not in the shared posts.
2. After the last app update, we can't share posts with images at all. When we share the image - we receive the error (see image attached). Also as we checked other apps and they have the same problems with sharing posts with images.

Here a screenshot with an error message:

[image: LinkedIn app sharing error message]

Could anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what is your image file size & dimension?

Comment: Not sure.. there may be problem with linkedin or ios native logic. But you can check with the following. 1.The image should be at least 80 x 150px for best results.
2. try setting image URL instead of image data. 
reference: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin#methods

Comment: @Venkat, thanks for your reply. Image size : 610x666.

Comment: @SerhiiLondarDid you ever find an answer to this? Still seems to be an issue with every app I've tried sharing form on iOS 10.

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH No. We still have this issue in our app(

Comment: @SerhiiLondar any updated regarding this issue? Got any solution?